# Synchronizing data between local data and database

Tags: ios, swift, database, validation, synchronization

I wanted to ask for the best solution in synchronizing large amounts of data between the local data storage and a database. (Offline and Online synchronization)

let's say i have two tables and these tables have customers.
Now if i change some data e.g name for the customer, i have to send this to the server before i can pull the server side update, otherwise there would be a conflict.

Let's image the app is offline and has no internet connection so all the changes are made locally.

What i have been doing up till now is save the initial data pull locally and set queue states for the changes. If i change the name for the customer i would set the customer queue state to AWAITING and once the application gets internet and is back online, i would run a query and get all customers that have queue state AWAITING and send that to the database for synchronization, before i can do a data pull.

I believe this model is called Eventual consistency which i think is not very good, and wonder if there is a better way to do this.

I had a different idea where i would create some Queue where every change is stored in JSON and once the app gets internet the queue would be run and all of these API calls would be sent, but this would work weirdly if let's say i change the customers name from John to Matt, then back from Matt to John, and at this point 2 new api calls would be added to the queue. First where i change to Matt and next where i change back to John, which is what we started with and is therefor not needed, but these changes would be very hard to keep track of, and as it is already now it feels like the synchronization is very unstable.

Do you guys know any better approaches for synchronization between (Offline and Online) local changes and the serverside database?

Comment: Why don't you just use an already available, free 3rd party framework that's been designed for mobile databases and cloud syncing, such as Firebase or Realm Object Server?

Comment: Because we already utilize AWS Aurora which is very fast and reliable and changing to Realm that is not as fast and reliable, and also re-doing all of our API calls would be major task.

Also how does it work offline if the app loses wifi, how does i keep track of the changes.

Comment: Realm's solution is a mobile first solution, so it works out-of-the box without internet connection as well. I don't know if you ever worked with `Realm` (judging from the questions in the comment don't think so), so I don't know where you got the metrics (not fast and reliable) from, but in my experience it is both fast and reliable. Using an already existing database solution would solve these synchronization issues for you, since it is designed for mobile usage.

Comment: Hi Steelzeh. I think your question is difficult to answer without understanding your data design. Data synchronisation strategy can't really be divorced from data design. In general today things have moved wholly away from relational data and the preservation of First Normal Form and if the data is part of e.g. a large document, generally the document will be highly de-normalised. Is every record in your data model atomic with regard to other records and synchronisation?